# how to get multiple screen data and submit from final screen in android?

Tags: android, class, android-activity

I have five screens like homeDetails,addressDetails,officeDetails, positionDetails,applyDetails. Finally all these details submit from applyDetails class. Here my doubt is, when i click submit button in applyDetails class, then send all classes information to server. So how can i get homeDetails,addressDetails,officeDetails,positionDetails data in applyDetails class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save data using SharedPreferences.

for ex. i wanna save a string in MainActivity class

```
sp = getSharedPreferences("saveData", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
ed.putString("string1", stringToBeSent);
ed.commit();
```

Now to retrieve it in another class i will use

```
sp = getSharedPreferences("saveData", 0);
String retrievedString = sp.getString("string1","");
```

Comment: after save i need to submit this data from applyDetails class. Can i get these activities details in applyDetails ? how? any example

Comment: You can use `sp = getSharedPreferences("saveData", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
ed.putString("string1", stringToBeSent);
ed.commit();` in any activity to save the data.When in another activity,you can use `sp = getSharedPreferences("saveData", 0);
String retrievedString = sp.getString("string1","");` to fetch the same data saved from another activity.

Comment: nice tip, tour tips is very helped. I need to learn some more things in SharedPreferences, so can u kindly send any example links...thanks